# Is it appropriate to extend List to add fields

Tags: java, oop, collections

The question is framed for `List` but easily applies to others in the java collections framework.

For example, I would say it is certainly appropriate to make a new `List` sub-type to store something like a counter of additions since it is an integral part of the list's operation and doesn't alter that it "is a list". Something like this:

```
public class ChangeTrackingList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
   private int changeCount;
   ...
   @Override public boolean add(E e) {
      changeCount++;
      return super.add(e);
   }
   // other methods likewise overridden as appropriate to track change counter
}
```

However, what about adding additional functionality out of the knowledge of a list ADT, such as storing arbitrary data associated with a list element? Assuming the associated data was properly managed when elements are added and removed, of course. Something like this:

```
public class PayloadList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
   private Object[] payload;
   ...
   public void setData(int index, Object data) {
      ... // manage 'payload' array
      payload[index] = data;
   }
   public Object getData(int index) {
      ... // manage 'payload' array, error handling, etc.
      return payload[index];
   }
}
```

In this case I have altered that it is "just a list" by adding not only additional functionality (behavior) but also additional state. Certainly part of the purpose of type specification and inheritance, but is there an implicit restriction (taboo, deprecation, poor practice, etc.) on Java collections types to treat them specially?

For example, when referencing this `PayloadList` as a `java.util.List`, one will mutate and iterate as normal and ignore the payload. This is problematic when it comes to something like persistence or copying which does not expect a `List` to carry additional data to be maintained. I've seen many places that accept an object, check to see that it "is a list" and then simply treat it as `java.util.List`. Should they instead allow arbitrary application contributions to manage specific concrete sub-types?

Since this implementation would constantly produce issues in instance slicing (ignoring sub-type fields) is it a bad idea to extend a collection in this way and always use composition when there is additional data to be managed? Or is it instead the job of persistence or copying to account for all concrete sub-types including additional fields?

Comment: You know, `List` itself is an interface, so only an interface can extend it. What you're doing it is not exactly "creating something that is a `List`", but rather "creating a special kind of `ArrayList`".

Comment: "Favor composition over inheritance", "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it". See Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 16, which discusses exactly this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I meant "extend" in the sense of "is-a" or any sub-type and not just with the keyword `extends`. Of course `ArrayList` is a concrete class and `List` is an interface; the use of `ArrayList` was for the examples and not for the heart of the question.

Comment: If you really want it to be a `List<E>` instance, the "is-a" concept works perfectly with interfaces as they're contracts per se. You should be very careful extending a class, a concrete implementation. Just extend the `List<E>` interface with the `PayloadList<E>`, and then just implement a decorator with a backing `List<E>`. Thus you can pass any list instance as the backing one, say `LinkedList<E>` rather than `ArrayList<E>`, or even any `PayloadList<E>`, or even whatever else you would like to use instead in the future.

Comment: For instance, just take a look at synchronized wrappers for collections and maps in JDK `Collections.synchronized###(...)` methods. They all can accept any implementation of `List<E>` or `Map<K, V>` just having trivial implementations. If they weren't designed that way, I guess, there could be synced decorators bloat like `SynchronizedArrayList<E>`, `SynchronizedLinkedList<E>`, `SynchronizedHashMap<K, V>` and so on, just because of inheritance and just to cover all existing implementations. Just think in terms of interfaces and favor composition over inheritance for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One aspect you should consider is that all classes that inherit from `AbstractList` are *value classes*. That means that they have meaningful `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods, therefore two lists are judged to be equal even if they are not the same instance of any class.

Furthermore, the `equals()` contract from `AbstractList` allows any list to be compared with the current list - not just a list with the same implementation.

Now, if you add a *value item* to a value class when you extend it, you need to include that value item in the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. Otherwise you will allow two `PayloadList` lists with different payloads to be considered "the same" when somebody uses them in a map, a set, or just a plain `equals()` comparison in any algorithm.

But in fact, it's impossible to extend a value class by adding a value item! You'll end up breaking the `equals()` contract, either by breaking symmetry (A plain `ArrayList` containing `[1,2,3]` will return true when compared with a `PayloadList` containing `[1,2,3]` with a payload of `[a,b,c]`, but the reverse comparison won't return true). Or you'll break transitivity.

This means that basically, the only proper way to extend a value class is by adding non-value behavior (e.g. a list that logs every `add()` and `remove()`). The only way to avoid breaking the contract is to use composition. And it has to be composition that **does not implement `List` at all** (because again, other lists will accept anything that implements `List` and gives the same values when iterating it).

<sub>This answer is based on item 8 of Effective Java, 2nd Edition, by Joshua Bloch</sub>

Comment: Ah, this is it. What I was forgetting is that the API contract for `List` requires `equals` to be true iff they have the same size and all corresponding pairs of elements between the lists are equal. So the answer to my question then is generalized to simply following the contract: if you can extend the class and add state while obeying the contract, then it is okay, so there is nothing particularly special about the collections API. This also explains why libraries safely assume a list is simply a collection of elements and need not have special cases for concrete sub-types. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a matter of opinion, but personally I would advise against extending classes like `ArrayList` in almost all circumstances, and favour composition instead.

Even your `ChangeTrackingList` is rather dodgy. What does

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

do? Does it increment `changeCount` twice, or not at all? It depends on whether `ArrayList.addAll()` uses `add()`, which is an implementation detail you should not have to worry about. You would also have to keep your methods in sync with the `ArrayList` methods. For example, at present `addAll(Collection<?> collection)` *is* implemented on top of `add()`, but if they decided in a future release to check first if `collection instanceof ArrayList`, and if so use `System.arraycopy` to directly copy the data, you would have to change your `addAll()` method to only increment `changeCount` by `collection.size()` if the collection is an `ArrayList` (otherwise it gets done in `add()`).

Also if a method is ever added to `List` (this happened with `forEach()` and `stream()` for example) this would cause problems if you were using that method name to mean something else. This can happen when extending `abstract` classes too, but at least an `abstract` class has no state, so you are less likely to be able to cause too much damage by overriding methods.

I would still use the `List` interface, and ideally extend `AbstractList`. Something like this

```
public final class PayloadList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {

    private final ArrayList<E> list;
    private final Object[] payload;

    // details missing
}
```

That way you have a class that implements `List` and makes use of `ArrayList` without you having to worry about implementation details.

(By the way, in my opinion, the class `AbstractList` is amazing. You only have to override `get()` and `size()` to have a functioning `List` implementation and methods like `containsAll()`, `toString()` and `stream()` all just work.)

Comment: The note in the code `// other methods likewise overridden as appropriate to track change counter` was intended to handle the addAll, add(int, E), sort, etc. Presumably additional methods on `List` would have to use existing API since it is an interface or existing subtypes would break, so that's a different argument. If I extend from `AbstractList` instead of `ArrayList` the question is still the same: is a java collection "special" when it comes to slicing and treating it as the abstract type?

Comment: @PaulBilnoski No matter how many methods of `ArrayList` you override you cannot be sure of getting `ChangeTrackingList` to work as desired because, short of reading all the source-code, you can't be sure when the methods are called by other methods. You also have to keep you code in sync with the original (they could easily decide to change the implementation of `addAll` at any point, and you would have to change your `addAll` method too). The difference between `AbstractList` and `ArrayList` is that `AbstractList` is clearly and carefully designed to be extended.

Comment: The composition approach occured to me as an option, but it can not be implemented in a way that guarantees that semantics are preseved in all cases. The main culprit is the the get(index), set(index, item) method-pair, which client code expecting a list could use to re-order items. There is no way to track changes in a way that will reasonably preserve the associated payload.

Comment: @Durandal You're right. If a client uses `Collections.swap` for example, the data associated to the items could get lost. I guess you could do it by replacing the `Object[]` with a `WeakHashMap<E, Object>` or something. But I agree with you that if your class does *too* much beyond what is normally expected from a `List`, or it would be too much of a burden to allow too many of the optional `List` operations, it might be better to simply say it's not a `List` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The following is all just opinion, the question invites opinionated answers (I think its borderline to not being approiate for SO).

While your approach is workable in some situations, I'd argue its bad design and it is very brittle. Its also pretty complicated to cover all loopholes (maybe even impossible, for example when the list is sorted by means *other* than List.sort).

If you require extra data to be stored and managed it would be better integrated into the list items themselves, or the data could be associated using existing collection types like Map.

If you really need an association list type, consider making it *not* an instance of java.util.List, but a specialized type with specialized API. That way no accidents are possible by passing it where a plain list is expected.

Comment: You are right, it does invite opinions. I guess what I am looking for is if there are known best practices against this. I think this is less "pure opinion" compared to source code formatting style and more in line with something a lint tool may detect and warn about as a bad practice. That aside, the example to store extra data is just an example, and would be complex, but the question is just about "additional non-pure-list data" of some form. Making it not-a-list is another option, but seems generally the same as the list composition option.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is not `final`, you can always extend it. Everything else is subjective and a matter of opinion.

My opinion is to favor composition over inheritance, since in the long run, inheritance produces low cohesion and high coupling, which is the opposite of a good OO design. But this is just my opinion.